# Font color property in PDF using perl PDF::Create

Tags: perl, pdf

How to set the font-color property when creating PDF through the Perl module [PDF::Create](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Create)? The below is the code snippet I am using. How can I set the font color property here?

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use PDF::Create;
use PDF::Image::JPEG;

print "PDF with Image\n";

#Create
my $pdf = new PDF::Create(
    'filename' => "./image_embed_test.pdf",
    'Version'  => 1.2,
    'PageMode' => 'UseNone',
    'Author'   => 'Madhan',
    'Title'    => 'My PDF',
);

# Prepare 2 fonts
my $f1 = $pdf->font('Subtype'  => 'Type1',
                    'Encoding' => 'WinAnsiEncoding',
                    'BaseFont' => 'Helvetica');

my $f2 = $pdf->font('Subtype'  => 'Type1',
                    'Encoding' => 'WinAnsiEncoding',
                    'BaseFont' => 'Helvetica-Bold');

my $f3 = $pdf->font('Subtype'  => 'Type1',
                    'Encoding' => 'WinAnsiEncoding',
                    'BaseFont' => 'Helvetica-Bold');


my $root = $pdf->new_page('MediaBox' => [ 0, 0, 612, 792 ]);

my @page;
$page[1]=$root->new_page;

my $jpg1 = $pdf->image('./logo1.jpg');
$page[1]->image( 'image'  => $jpg1,
                 'xscale' => 0.5,
                 'yscale' => 0.5,
                 'xpos'   => 56,
                 'ypos'   => 698);

   $page[1]->stringc($f2, 8, 484, 738, "Add line 1");
   $page[1]->stringc($f2, 8, 521, 718, "City");
   $page[1]->stringc($f2, 8, 530, 698, "Phone");
   $page[1]->stringc($f3, 8, 530, 698, "myid@example.com");

$pdf->close;
```

In the `$f3` for the mail id link I need to set the color as blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `setrgbcolor` method from [PDF::Create::Page](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Create::Page#setrgbcolor-r-g-b).

> **setrgbcolor($r, $g, $b)**
>   Sets the fill colors used for normal text or filled objects.

It looks like you need to set that before you run the `stringc` operation at it will just set the color for all subsequent operations. So you turn it to blue, write your blue text, and turn it back to black (or default).

```
$page[$num]->setrgbcolor(1, 0, 0); # blue
$page[$num]->stringc($f3, 8, 530, 698, "myid@example.com");
$page[$num]->setrgbcolor(0, 0, 0); # black
```

Directly below `setrgbcolor` there is [`setrgbcolorstroke`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Create::Page#setrgbcolorstroke-r-g-b), which explains that the parameters are values between `0` and `1`.

Comment: I found this by checking what other classes are included in [PDF::Create](https://metacpan.org/release/PDF-Create) and then simply searching for color in the ::Page documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate help